# Discord.py client.run and bot.run in one code

Tags: python, discord.py

Not sure that I need to use the both runs at the same time, but:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy.connection import Client
from telnetlib import DM
from typing_extensions import Required
import discord
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands
from dislash import InteractionClient, Option, OptionType
from dislash.interactions import *

client = discord.Client()

from message import *
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    User_id = message.author.id
    
    if message.channel.id == 1009530463108476968:
        NewMessage = message.content.split(' ', 1)[0]
        LimitLenght = len(NewMessage) + 11
        
        if len(message.clean_content) >= LimitLenght:
            await message.delete()
            await message.author.send("Hello, " + f"<@{User_id}>" +  "\nPlease, don't send any messages that break the **Counting-game** rules!\nIt's forbidden to post a comment that is longer than 10 characters.")

        # More code

#=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=#

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
inter_client = InteractionClient(bot)
@inter_client.slash_command(name="help", description="Shows the help-menu")

async def help(ctx):
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Test project", description="*The blue text is clickable.*\n⠀", color=0x0000ff)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Rules", value='To see rules write **/Rules**\n⠀', inline=False)
    await ctx.reply(embed=embedVar, delete_after=180)


bot.run('ToKeN')
client.run('ToKeN')
```

If you run this code and comment the "bot.run('ToKeN')", the first part of the code will work (def on_message), however the command '/help' will not work. If you change it (comment 'client.run('ToKeN')'), the command '/help' will work, but def on_message not.

What are the possible solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.run`s block each other and prevent from running. You shouldn't be using a client *and* a bot anyway. Use one `commands.Bot` instead. It subclasses a `Client` and it should be able to do everything you can do with the client.

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
inter_client = InteractionClient(bot)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    ...

@inter_client.slash_command(name="help", description="Shows the help-menu")
async def help(ctx):
    ...

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: So, I need to remove ```client = discord.Client()``` and ```client.run('ToKeN')``` and just leave ```bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")``` with ```bot.run(token)```?

Comment: Yes, but move the `bot` to the top so you can use it for the events.